# Spark rdd write to Hbase

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hbase, spark-streaming

I am able to read the messages from Kafka using the below code:

```
val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(50)) 
val topicmap = Map("test" -> 1)
val lines = KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc,"127.0.0.1:2181", "test-consumer-group",topicmap)
```

But, I am trying to read each message from Kafka and putting into HBase. This is my code to write into HBase but no success.

```
lines.foreachRDD(rdd => {
  rdd.foreach(record => {
    val i = +1
    val hConf = new HBaseConfiguration() 
    val hTable = new HTable(hConf, "test") 
    val thePut = new Put(Bytes.toBytes(i)) 
    thePut.add(Bytes.toBytes("cf"), Bytes.toBytes("a"), Bytes.toBytes(record)) 
  })
})
```

Answer (score 5):

Well, you are not actually executing the Put, you are mereley creating a Put request and adding data to it. What you are missing is an

```
hTable.put(thePut);
```

Comment: My mistake. I missed to mention that it though I had it as part of my code. The question here is : How to pass each message from Kafka to Hbase? I am able to read the messages from Kafka but when in the foreachRDD it is not able to port that message to Hbase. Did I do anything wrong in calling foreachRDD?

Answer (score 3):

> Adding other answer!!

You can use `foreachPartition` to establish connection at **executor level** to be more efficient **instead of each row** which is costly operation.

```
lines.foreachRDD(rdd => {

    rdd.foreachPartition(iter => {

      val hConf = new HBaseConfiguration() 
      val hTable = new HTable(hConf, "test") 

      iter.foreach(record => {
        val i = +1
        val thePut = new Put(Bytes.toBytes(i)) 
        thePut.add(Bytes.toBytes("cf"), Bytes.toBytes("a"), Bytes.toBytes(record)) 

        //missing part in your code
        hTable.put(thePut);
      })
    })
})
```