# Iterating Through Spark DataFrame Takes Huge Time and Fails with Error OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded

Tags: apache-spark, foreach, apache-spark-sql, hbase, out-of-memory

I am processing 5M records present in XML. I load them in Spark Dataframe and then try to load the same to HBase using dataframe foreach method. I get out of memory error after few processing time around the foreach itself or extremely slow loading. Can anyone suggest any solution or better approach?

**Code**:

```
val xmlSchemaXML = StructType(Array(
    StructField("A", StringType, nullable = true),
    StructField("B", StringType, nullable = true),
    StructField("C", StringType, nullable = true),
    StructField("D", StringType, nullable = true))
  )

  //Get File In DataFrame
  var dfXML = sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.xml")
    .option("rootTag", "ABC")
    .option("rowTag", "AB")
    .schema(xmlSchemaXML)
    .load("file:///home/xyz.xml")
    .withColumn("as_of_date", current_date())
    .withColumn("last_updated_date", current_timestamp())


  //Create HBase Configuration
  val hBaseConf = HBaseConfiguration.create()

  //Set HBase Configurations
  hBaseConf.set("hadoop.security.authentication", "kerberos")
  hBaseConf.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", cluster)
  hBaseConf.set("hbase.zookeeper.property.client.port", "2181")

  //Login Using KeyTab
  UserGroupInformation.setConfiguration(hBaseConf)
  UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromKeytab("user", "file:///tmp/keytab.keytab")

  println("Creating Connection With HBase...")


  val hBaseAdmin = new HBaseAdmin(hBaseConf)

  /** *************Check if Table Already Exists or Create One ***************/

  if (!hBaseAdmin.isTableAvailable("ns:table_name")) {
    println("ns:table_name does not exist...")
    val tableDescriptor = new HTableDescriptor(TableD.valueOf("ns:table_name"))
    val columnDescriptor = new HColumnDescriptor(Bytes.toBytes("cf"))
    columnDescriptor.setVersions(1, 15)

    try {
      tableDescriptor.addFamily(columnDescriptor)
      hBaseAdmin.createTable(tableDescriptor)
      println("ns:table_name created...")
    }
    catch {
      case _: Throwable => println("table creation failed...")
    }
  }


  /** **************GET RECORD COUNT FROM ns:table_name ****************/
  var rowKeyCount: Long = 0
  try {
    hBaseConf.set(TableInputFormat.INPUT_TABLE, "ns:table_name")
    val hBaseRDD = sc.newAPIHadoopRDD(hBaseConf, classOf[TableInputFormat], classOf[ImmutableBytesWritable], classOf[Result])
    println("Number of Records found in ns:table_name: " + hBaseRDD.count())
    rowKeyCount = hBaseRDD.count()
    println("====================================================================================")
  }
  catch {
    case _: Throwable => println("table reading failed...")
    case npe: NullPointerException =>
      println("Result NullPointerException: Table does not exist")
      rowKeyCount = 0
  }

  println("----------------START READING DATA FROM DATAFRAME AND LOAD TO HBASE----------------")

  //Create HTable for ns:table_name
  val hTable = new HTable(hBaseConf, "ns:table_name")

  println("Total Rows in File: " + dfXML.count())


  var A = ""
  var B = ""
  var C = ""
  var D = ""
  var as_of_date = ""
  var last_updated_date = ""

  dfXML.limit(100000).collect().foreach(f = elem => {

    //println(elem)
    rowKeyCount = rowKeyCount + 1

    //println("0")
     if (elem.getString(0) == null)
       A = ""
     else
    A = elem.getString(0)

    //println("1")
    if (elem.getString(1) == null)
      B = ""
    else
    B = elem.getString(1)


    //println("2")
    if (elem.getString(2) == null)
      C = ""
    else
    C = elem.getString(2)

    //println("3")
    if (elem.getString(3) == null)
      D = ""
    else
    D = elem.getString(3)

    //println("4")        
    as_of_date = elem.getDate(4).toString

    //println("5")        
    last_updated_date = elem.getTimestamp(5).toString


    var put = new Put(rowKeyCount.toString.getBytes()); //Store RowKey

    put.addColumn("cf".getBytes(), "A".getBytes(), A.getBytes())
    put.addColumn("cf".getBytes(), "B".getBytes(), B.getBytes())
    put.addColumn("cf".getBytes(), "C".getBytes(), C.getBytes())
    put.addColumn("cf".getBytes(), "D".getBytes(), D.getBytes())
    put.addColumn("cf".getBytes(), "as_of_date".getBytes(), as_of_date.getBytes())
    put.addColumn("cf".getBytes(), "last_updated_date".getBytes(), last_updated_date.getBytes())

    //Commit to HBaseDB        
    hTable.put(put);
    //println(rowKeyCount + " : Record written to HBase...")

  })

  hTable.flushCommits();
```

Comment: You don't use `DataFrame.foreach`, you `collect` data. Failure on large dataset is almost guaranteed to happen. Use [`foreachPartition`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50107222/9613318) instead.

Comment: thanks a lot for your response. I changed the code as below and it is now giving me not serializable issue

Comment: we are not seeing any change...

Comment: df.foreachPartition(partitionOfRecords  =>
partitionOfRecords.foreach(elem => {

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you need to do is increase default 100 partitions to something more sensible to your workload. Please start with `df.repartition(1000). foreachPartition(...` and then see if 1000 is too much or too little.

5M records doesn't seem to be a big amount, most likely you either have large records or not enough heap space allocated on executors.

Comment: Thanks nefo_x. Should I pleace collect() as well to make it parellelizable? dfCompany.repartition(1000).collect().foreachPartition

Comment: CeeJay, I don’t think you’re able to place ‘foreachPartition’ (rdd scoped, paralizable) after ‘collect’ (driver jvm scoped, single thread).

Comment: That’s correct. As i have a dataframe. Can you please suggest best practices of loading dataframe to HBase. Especially when you have to assign custom rowkey and handle null values in dataframe?

Comment: Closer look at your query revealed two things: 1) don’t try to get rowkey as count/auto incremental value, as this won’t work as you expect in map/reduce environment. Use time-based uuid or something like that 2) Null/default values are better handled in ‘.withColumn’ statements of dataframe, anyway you need to do that in scope of rdd. 3) if you’re doing ‘htable.put’ within ‘foreachPartition’, original stacktrace is no longer accurate and not making sense. Maybe if you would post a bit more context, like part where you turn xml into df and new exception stacktrace, better advice will come

Comment: I have put my complete code above in original question. Kindly take a look and suggest

Comment: I see... my suggestion would be: turn data frame into RDD, iterate over elements in foreachPartition, where you will be creating separate hbase connections and putting data to a table - see other example in this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/49893573/277035.

Comment: If this would be too complex and your file size won’t extend few hundred gigabytes and files are not stored on HDFS - just use streaming XML parser (see example at https://softwarecave.org/2014/02/18/parse-xml-document-using-streaming-api-for-xml-stax/) and write to Hbase in flushable batches directly without using Spark.

Comment: CeeJay, so, what approach did help in the end? make sure to accept the answer ;)

Comment: I did the rdd and repartition but along with that I grouped 10000 rows and added each group to a PUT Array and at the end of each group submitted that to HBase. It takes less than 3 minutes now